# Mysterious Orphan Text

Tags: jquery, css, text

I'm using a sliding the [jquery.hslides.js] plugin for a project... I've never seen anything like this but when I changed the overall width of the sliding container, out of nowhere I have these orphan bits of text floating around.  I have ZERO clue where they came from... they're not selectable.  You can see them here: http://cld.ly/821d8m.

Has anyone else seen anything like this.  The fact that they're not selectable is really throwing me for a loop.

Link to the live site: http://cld.ly/301d8s login with admin / sslPabe938v

Comment: Have you tried to see what styles are getting applied to the bits of text with something like Firebug?

Comment: Yessir.  I have.  Although, do you know how to hold the :hover state while using "inpsect" in Firebug?

Comment: @Brian, a link to a live page or some code would greatly help. Most likely you need `overflow:hidden` on the right `div`, or a `position: relative` somewhere.

Comment: Updated the question to include link to live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is the bio from the previous instructor (it's most obvious with Lotus Niraja and the first "Instructor's Name"), and it's visible because the background images don't fill up the bio element. Try setting a background color on `.sliding`.

Answer (score 2):

outis is correct. It looks like when the widths were increased, the background images no longer fill the entire new width, and you can see some text from the previous instructor. There is no background color set on `ul#sliding_panels li.p1` - it is set to transparent. Try removing `transparent` from `background` here, as the color is actually set in `.sliding`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem when using with `blueprint css`, Its very hard to find out the right place and finally when I figured it out, the problem is if the parent div has smaller width than the child div, the contents in the child div can repeat like that, the ghost text you are seeing is not ghost, its some text repeating from the child div text. I don't know exactly which property is causing it, but try changing the width attribute on the parent containers all the way and see when its fixed, use firebug.